Transaction history is not available from this node : Solana validator RPC setup
Even though i have successfully setup solana-validator(mainnet) RPC(--no-voting) node in my computer and the newwork catchup also success as solana-validator --ledger /mnt/ledger monitor also shows slots proceeded there is no slots left behind and everything seems to be working fine but when i try to run "getTransaction" rpc HTTP method(from curl/nodejs(web3js)) its throwing me error as {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32011,"message":"Transaction history is not available from this node"},"id":1}.
i am calling the method as curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "getTransaction", "params": [ "FB68vPpccUhKTtsKTZEeeAAH6LUktChSWVY5yXzrFW3PAWmuhZ2vbBzTgnksDERvLJ9MNUweUb9AukafaWyYY9c", { "encoding": "base58" } ] } '
which i am not sure why its showing like this.(i am kind of new to solana validator RPC node actually).
my validator.sh:

#!/bin/bash
exec solana-validator \
    --identity /home/sol/validator-keypair.json \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --known-validator 5D1fNXzvv5NjV1ysLjirC4WY92RNsVH18vjmcszZd8on \
    --known-validator dDzy5SR3AXdYWVqbDEkVFdvSPCtS9ihF5kJkHCtXoFs \
    --known-validator eoKpUABi59aT4rR9HGS3LcMecfut9x7zJyodWWP43YQ \
    --known-validator 7XSY3MrYnK8vq693Rju17bbPkCN3Z7KvvfvJx4kdrsSY \
    --known-validator Ft5fbkqNa76vnsjYNwjDZUXoTWpP7VYm3mtsaQckQADN \
    --known-validator 9QxCLckBiJc783jnMvXZubK4wH86Eqqvashtrwvcsgkv \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --no-voting \
    --ledger /mnt/ledger \
    --accounts /mnt/accounts \
    --log /home/sol/solana-rpc.log \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
#    --private-rpc \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --limit-ledger-size 100000000 \
#    --account-index program-id \
#    --account-index spl-token-mint \
#    --account-index spl-token-owner \
    --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
    --enable-cpi-and-log-storage


where i believe i have enabled the transaction history using enable-rpc-transaction-history and  limit-ledger-size as 100000000.
Notably i have tried subscribing to onLogs event using nodejs as connection.onLogs function also which i am not receiving a single log from it. its just staying blank.
I hope i have provided enough details so you can help me... Please
I am just not sure what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance.

That's very strange, it looks like that error should only be returned when rpc transaction history is not configured: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/8c5a33a81a0504fd25d0465bed35d153ff84819f/rpc/src/rpc.rs#L1581 -- can you also try adding --enable-extended-tx-metadata-storage?

thats correct its strange! anyway i will check with the --enable-extended-tx-metadata-storage as well.
